# Swift 3: Overload func in extension

Tags: swift, parameters, overloading

I like to overload a function:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
    mutating func remove(object: Element) {
        if let index = self.index(of: object) {
            self.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}
```

But I get an error, that the call

```
primary.remove(dupp)
```

is not matching any overload. If I use my own name, the call is matching and the compiler wants to add "object:" before the first parameter. So the call seems to be alright, but what is wrong? If I add add "object:" manualy it works fine.

Comment: Which version of swift are you using? Because it doesn't compile in swift 2.2.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. `primary.remove(object: dump)` is the correct way to call your method. If you don't want an argument label then define it as `mutating func remove(_ object: Element)`.

Comment: It is the advice of the compiler, that there is no overload when not adding "object:" directly. But your hint is great, I will add "mutating". Thank you.